# Convert values from Access Combo Box to string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to convert the values from combo box to a string so I can add that string to a variable, to a function to eventually add to a database. 
Here is my sub that grabs text from my form and from the combo box:

```
Private Sub cbRowStudentGrade_Change()


  Course_ID.SetFocus
  rowCourseID = Course_ID.Text

  StuRed_ID.SetFocus
  rowStudentRedID = StuRed_ID.Text

  cbRowStudentGrade.SetFocus
  cbRowStudentGrade = cbRowStudentGrade.Column(0)

  CurrentDb.Execute "qryInputGrades"


  MsgBox (rowCourseID)
  MsgBox (rowStudentRedID)
  MsgBox (cbRowStudentGrade)


  Requery
  Repaint
End Sub
```

And here are the functions that I am using as criteria in my Access query builder.

```
Public Function funcRowCourseID() As String

  funcRowCourseID = rowCourseID

End Function


Public Function funcRowStudentRedID() As String

  funcRowStudentRedID = rowStudentRedID

End Function


Public Function funcCbRowStudentGrade() As String

  funcCbRowStudentGrade = cbRowStudentGrade

End Function
```

My query:

```
INSERT INTO tblRegistrationGrade ( Red_ID, Course_ID, Grade )
VALUES (funcRowStudentRedID(), funcRowCourseID(), funcCbRowStudentGrade());
```

I think there is a datatype mismatch between the database and what the combobox value actually is. But, if there were a datatype mismatch wouldn't there be an error stating as such? My database requires `short text`, which these are.

Comment: I have a few thoughts, although I'm not specifically answering you: 1) You'd be better to use combobox_afterupdate than combobox_change. 2) The statement cbRowStudentGrade = cbRowStudentGrade.Column(0) makes no sense: if the bound column is 0, all this statement does is assign its current value to itself. 3) Your public functions lack arguments, which implies that the functions are defined in your form, but public functions in a form are not recognised by a query unless the form is open

Comment: You might wish to add your query to your post as well

Comment: It seems like the function is being run before the sub has populated the variables.

Comment: The name of the variables and the name of the subroutine are identical. I changed the name of the variable to something different and it works fine.

Comment: Further: Values from Combo- and ListBoxes are always strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this way too complicated.

You can directly refer from your INSERT query to the form controls:

```
INSERT INTO tblRegistrationGrade ( Red_ID, Course_ID, Grade )
VALUES (Forms!myForm!StuRed_ID, Forms!myForm!Course_ID, Forms!myForm!cbRowStudentGrade);
```

and get rid of almost all of the code, except calling the query.

As John wrote, it would be better placed in `cbRowStudentGrade_AfterUpdate()`.

---

Or, instead of the INSERT query, use a `DAO.Recordset` with `AddNew`, see:
[How to: Add a Record to a DAO Recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243801%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

There you can also directly use the values from your from controls without worrying about data types.